# Can a std::function member have access to other members?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am making a small tower defence game in order to practice C++. I know other languages, but have done little actual development in C++.
In this game I'll have several buildings, so I made a class like so:

```
class Building
{
private:
    sf::Sprite& sprite;
    float timer = 0;
    void update(float delta);
};
```

Now, I'll have many different buildings, but they should all have the same members. Now, in Java I would (have to) make a subclass for each different type of building, bu I was thinking, can I change `void update(float delta);` to `std::function<void(float)> update;` and have factory funtions to create the different buildings? What I imagine is something like this:

In building.h:

```
class Building
{
private:
    sf::Sprite& sprite;
    float timer = 0;
    std::function<void(float)> update;
};
```

And in building.cpp

```
Building getBuildingA()
{
    Building b;
    b.sprite = /* ... */
    b.update = [](float delta) {
        std::cout << timer++ << std::endl;
    };
    return b;
}
```

But of course, I cannot actually access the variable timer there. Is there a way I can do something similar?

Comment: By capturing `this`?

Comment: You can't initialize a reference by assignment like that. It has to be initialized in an initializer list.

Comment: You can work around the privacy issue by making getBuildingA a static member function of Building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the lambda capture `this`. A better solution is probably something like

```
class Building
{
private:
    sf::Sprite& sprite;
    float timer = 0;
    std::function<void(Building*, float)> update_impl;
    void update(float x) { update_impl(this, x); }
};
```

But really, based on this fragment of your design it looks like you really *should* be using subclasses and virtual functions; this is the sort of thing they're *meant* for.

The typical application of `function` is when you pass function objects around -- e.g. to replace the Java paradigm of writing an interface class with a single method, especially in settings when you'd rather just write functions or lambdas rather than whole objects.

For object polymorphism, the main alternative to subclassing and virtual functions is to use templates and generic programming -- although that's mainly for when you need polymorphism to happen at *compile time*. (which, I imagine, is inappropriate for your circumstance)

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I see your point on subclassing. There are other issues here as well with my design, but it is done in an effort to explore what can be done with lambdas and the like.

Comment: For completeness, I can also imagine designs where a `function` is appropriate too; I don't have the complete picture here so that part of my advice depends on educated guessing.

Comment: Ah, I guess specifically wanting to experiment with `function` is a relevant part of the complete picture I'm missing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply capture `this`.
As an example:

```
struct S {
    auto foo() {
        return [this](){ this->bar(); };
    }

    void bar() { }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.foo()();
}
```

If you are using C++14, you can use an initializer list instead.
As an example:

```
#include<cassert>

struct S {
    auto foo() {
        return [timer = timer](){
            assert(timer == 42);
        };
    }

    int timer{42};
};

int main() {
    S s{};
    s.foo()();
}
```

This way, you'll get a copy-initialized variable named *timer* to be used within the body of the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the privacy issue by using a static-member function of Building to provide the factory class.

A secondary issue you're going to run into is that you're returning a Building by value, so, unless RVO happens you won't know the ultimate address of the object you are returning. You can work around this by having your "update()" function pass it's "this" as a parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Building {
    // C++ classes are private by default
    int timer_;
    std::function<void(Building*)> update_;

public:
    void update() {
        update_(this);
    }

    static Building getBuildingA() {
        Building b;
        b.timer_ = 42;
        b.update_ = [](Building* b) {
            b->timer_++;
            std::cout << b->timer_ << '\n';
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    Building b = Building::getBuildingA();
    b.update();
    return 0;
}
```

Working demo: http://ideone.com/1Jy6zI

But also be aware that you cannot *assign* a reference to initialize it, you *must* initialize it. Also be aware that C++ is not ref-counted by default, so your reference to the sprite can easily become a dangling reference.

You might want to consider a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a reference.